# Are Boolean orders axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory, boolean-algebra

Consider the class of Boolean algebras $(B, \vee, \land, ', 0,1)$. We define an order relation $\leq$ via $x \leq y$ iff $x \vee y = y$. I define a Boolean order to be any order isomorphic to such an order. Is the class of Boolean orders axiomatizable, and if it is, is it finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: Is the class of Boolean algebras axiomatizable? Is it finitely axiomatizable? Are the Boolean operations definable in tgerms of the order relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is **yes**, for exactly the same reason as in the case of [your earlier question about real closed fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045155/28111). Basically, there is a **definable process** for expanding a Boolean order into a Boolean algebra, and so we can "reverse" this to translate the Boolean *algebra* axioms into a set of Boolean *order* axioms. Moreover, since the former are finite so are the latter.

This is a special case of the general principle stated in the above-linked answer, which gives a general recipe for arguing that pseudoelementary classes are elementary (of course this doesn't always work but it does frequently work).