# A follow up to a previous question on peano structures

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms

This is a natural follow-up to my previous question on Peano structures and positive integer structures, here: [Are positive integer structures axiomatizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413969/are-positive-integer-structures-axiomatizable). In that question, I gave the Peano axioms for structures of the form $(N;0,S,+,*)$:

1. $\neg \exists x Sx = 0$
2. $\forall x \forall y (Sx = Sy \rightarrow x = y)$
3. The axiom schema of induction (which are really an infinite set of axioms)
4. $\forall x (x+0)=x$
5. $\forall x \forall y (x+Sy)=S(x+y)$
6. $\forall x (x*0)=0$
7. $\forall x \forall y (x*Sy)=((x*y)+x)$

Define the constant $n$ by $S...S0$, where there are $n$ $S$'s, and define the relation $\leq$ by $x \leq y \iff \exists z (x+z)=y$. It can be easily proven that the set $N_n := \{x \in N | n \leq x\}$ is closed under the constant $n$, the unary operation $S$, and also the binary operations $+$ and $*$. Therefore, we can form the structure $(N_n;n,S,+,*)$. I want to know, for each positive integer $n$, is the class of structures isomorphic to those structures a first-order axiomatizable class of structures? In my previous question, I asked this same question for the specific case of the positive integer $1$. I believe that the answer to my current question is also affirmative. If it is, I would also like an explicit axiomatization of that class of structures.

Comment: We can (again!) use the general fact used in my answer to your original question to get a positive answer (and explicit axiomatization) here: just build the appropriate interpretations.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The only trouble I am having is knowing what the appropriate axioms should be.  To take a specific example, let $n$ be $3$. What should the axioms be? Well, I guess Axioms 2, 5, and 7 would stay identical, Axiom 1 would replace $0$ with $3$, and the axiom schema of induction would replace $0$ with $3$ as the base case. But what should be put in place of axioms 4 and 6? That is where I am stuck on.

Comment: Let $\boxplus$, $\boxtimes$ be the "PA-versions" of the $+,\times$ of your structure; so e.g. $3\boxplus 3=3$, since $3$ in your structure should correspond to $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Your axioms should say that these $\boxplus,\boxtimes$ satisfy the PA-axioms, and additionally that they relate to $+,\times$ correctly (namely, the interpretation the other way "works").

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hmm, so maybe Axiom 4 should be $(x+3)=SSSx$, and Axiom 6 should be $(x*3)=(x+(x+x))$. Is this how the pattern works: For a positive integer $n$, the corresponding axiom 4 would be $(x+n)=S...Sx$, where there are $n$ $S$'s, and the corresponding axiom 6 would be $(x*n)=(x+(x+...x)...)$, where there are $n$ copies of $x$ in the right-hand side?